# Core Data: when is NSManagedObject inserted into a context and saved?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Here's my code:

```
for (NSString *filePaths in self.filesAdded) {
        FileAttachments *fileObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FileAttachments" inManagedObjectContext: context];
        fileObject.fileName = filePaths;
}

NSLog(@"before context->save");
if (![context save:&error]) ...
```

I'm trying to find the point when a `NSManagedObject` is **saved** in a context after being inserted for the first time. It seems `awakeFromInsert` is called when you call `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName]`, which is too early since none of the properties. I want to know when `[context save: error]` is called on those new `NSManagedObject`s, so I can save some more meta-information. Is there any good, clean way to do this? Something like `prepareForDeletion`, which is perfect for cleaning up objects.

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading your question, but aren't the managed objects saved when you call `[context save:&error]` in your last line? Or are you looking to receive some kind of notification of a save event, so that you can define a handler for it elsewhere?

Comment: What do you mean with *meta-information*? As Tim suggested, objects are saved in `[context save:error]` method.

Comment: I wanted a more centralize place, so I could put all the post-save code together. Right now, it will have be scattered everywhere I create the FileAttachments object and then save the context. prepareForDeletion is the perfect example. I guess there isn't anything equivalent "prepareToSave" method available.

Comment: Why not make a more centralized place, then, and call it from every method that's currently doing its own work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subclass your NSManagedObjectContext and override the save: method. You can run your "centralized" code at that point and then call save: of the super class. The call to the super class save: method is when it's actually saved, like others have said.

Answer (score 0):

NSManagedObjectContext generates a number of NSNotifications that might be what you are looking for. Check the documentation for NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.